# Unable to Connect mySQL database using C++in Eclipse

Tags: c++, mysql, eclipse

My Aim is to connect the C++ code to my database and update some information so i follow many Articles but none is solve my Problem..

**Here is the Problem...**

1. First I download the Boost,Mysql Server,C++ Connector and include in the eclipse but i think i did something Wrong because when i execute my Code such error is Shown check Screenshot:1 and Screenshot:2
2. Please Anyone Suggest me the Tutorial of Setup Eclipse C++
   [image: Figure_1]
   [image: Figure_2]

for the Code i followed the Below Link:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313272/connecting-to-mysql-from-eclipse-cdt)

Here is my Console output:

```
 12:14:54 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project C++_dev ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\Connector.C++ 1.1\\include" "-IC:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\include" "-IC:\\Software\\boost_1_61_0" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\C++_dev.o" "..\\src\\C++_dev.cpp" 
In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\include/cppconn/connection.h:33:0,
                 from C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\include/mysql_connection.h:30,
                 from ..\src\C++_dev.cpp:14:
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\include/cppconn/warning.h:40:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma warning (disable : 4290)
 ^
In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\include/cppconn/variant.h:38:0,
                 from C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\include/cppconn/connection.h:35,
                 from C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\include/mysql_connection.h:30,
                 from ..\src\C++_dev.cpp:14:
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\include/cppconn/exception.h:48:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma warning (disable : 4290)
 ^
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\include/cppconn/exception.h:52:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma warning(push)
 ^
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\include/cppconn/exception.h:53:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma warning(disable: 4275)
 ^
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\include/cppconn/exception.h:58:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma warning(pop)
 ^
g++ "-LC:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\Connector.C++ 1.1\\lib\\opt" "-LC:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\lib" -o C++_dev.exe "src\\C++_dev.o" "-lC:\\Program" "Files\\MySQL\\MySQL" Server "5.7\\lib\\mysqlclient.lib" 
g++: error: Files\MySQL\MySQL: No such file or directory
g++: error: Server: No such file or directory
g++: error: 5.7\lib\mysqlclient.lib: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you explain how "FILE NOT FOUND" is a MySQL connection problem?

Comment: i am not getting what are you saying?

Comment: The error says: "Jon_snow.exe not found", "Program file does not exist". How is that a MySQL connection problem?

Comment: Bcoz After adding mysql library the "Jon_snow.exe not found" problem is arise..... _Library Name:libmysql.lib,
mysqlcppconn-static.lib_ 
**And can you sir provide me the tutorial link where i set up whole connection and connect my code to db**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a code error, it's just that you misconfigured the MySQL connector in Eclipse.

You should be able to adapt this tutorial to your needs:

http://share-thevision.blogspot.com.es/2013/02/opencveclipse-on-windows.html

Just focus on how to link OpenCV libraries and it's the same (but paths) for MySQL

Comment: thanx for the answer